# Getting an error when I run react(vitest) unit test cases. I got to know It's due to the local image paths

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, vitest

**Error:**

stderr | unknown test
Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
at Object.dispatchError (E:\customer-dashboard\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\xhr-utils.js:63:19)
at Request. (E:\customer-dashboard\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:655:18)
at Request.emit (node:events:525:35)
at ClientRequest. (E:\customer-dashboard\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\http-request.js:127:14)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) undefined

**My code:**

```
<ReactSVG
      src='svg/heart_fill.svg'
      beforeInjection={(svg) => {
        svg.setAttribute('style', `width: ${width}; height: ${height}`);
      }}
      onClick={(e) => onClick && onClick(e)}
      {...props}
    />
```

I am defining my image paths as "src/assets/svg/s_cart.svg". However, when I run the unit test cases, I am getting errors like this one: "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000". I am not sure exactly what I need to do. Could you guys help me with this?

[Mock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0ea3.png)
I tried to mock the image path as show in the picture. Still I am facing the issue.

Comment: Please add your code as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I mocked the svg's thinking that was the issue too, but it still showed the same error.

If you mock the ReactSVG library it should work. You can either just mock it with the default mock:

```
vi.mock("react-svg")
```

And that should work, or if you wanted to display something in place of your svg you can mock the implementation as such:

```
    vi.mock("react-svg", () => {
    return {
        ReactSVG: vi.fn(() => <div>icon</div>),
    };
});
```

I suspect the component must be making some kind of network request under the hood which results in the error message you were seeing.

Thanks, Kurt